# Webscrapper that only adds new content

Tags: blocks, feeds

I would like to make a webscraper that updates the results of a volleybal team and puts the most recent score in a block on the frontpage.

Got the scrapper working with [kimono](https://www.kimonolabs.com/).

But this imports all the data.
The data that should be imported is [here](http://kwvbv.mavari.be/clubdetail.aspx?stamnr=w-2093#)

How can i just import the last score and put that in a block?
Thanks

Comment: What have you tired so far using `Feeds` or `Feeds Tamper` ... since that's what you tagged your posts with. Show us your code that imports all the data and maybe someone can tell you where to change the code so it does an `Update` instead.

Comment: Are you sure you want to import it ? Maybe just embed it using the API ?

https://www.kimonolabs.com/learn/create-kimonoblock